# Does 'evinced' make sense in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Is this sentence correct, and if so, does the word *evinced* make sense here?

> An aura of gloom and doom had also settled over the City, evinced by a
>   fusion of dirt, ash, building debris, and garbage that carpeted the
>   crumbling streets and a film of black soot that darkened the decrepit
>   concrete landscape.

Comment: What did your research on [*evince*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/evince) show? Why do you think it's a good word to use as you have?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Can I ask the same about your comment and it's utility? Words quite often might technically carry an appropriate meaning but not (in practice) be used in that context or mode.  : Yes cindy, it makes sense, though I might swap the order '......evincing an aura of gloom and doom,' (especially as establishing the context of an unusual/seldom seen word before it appears can be helpful) though I'm certainly no author.

Comment: @GiuPiete Your second sentence shows why [research is necessary](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed).

Comment: @Andrew Leach I read it as a grumpy criticism of the OP/Q, rather than advice to a user, my bad =)